# FontAwesome Kit vs CDN

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

Does anybody know what's the difference between using FontAwesome Kit and FontAwesome CDN?(in terms of advantages not the HTML tags)

Which one is better to use?

And what exactly is the Kit?

I've looked it up on their website but there's no clear explanation about the Kit concept!

All they say is:

> It's a little bundle of settings and icons that we think is the best way to use Font Awesome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience two benefits in using a "Kit" is it allows restricting icons to specific domains. This might not be crucial if you are using a free account, but if you are using a pro account it is a nice feature.  Plus, you can upload custom icons to your kit and call them like any other font awesome icon.  The domain restriction also prevents your custom icons from being used elsewhere.